# Mysql duplicate rows (ignore id + timestamp) without naming all other columns in the query?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have tried to make this question concise in the title.

There are many answers to similar questions, but all involve naming every column in the table in the query.

What I want is a query to show me duplicate rows, but to ignore one or two columns, and I would like to be able to do it like shown in this post [Return duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885602/return-duplicate-records), but without having to explicitly name every column in the table.

Is it possible?

Comment: To add the context, what happened this time is that due to bad design, I got a bunch of duplicate records in a table with over 60 columns from submit form reloads. Once again, it's bothering me that I can't type a quick query to find the duplicates, in which only the unique ID and timestamp are different.

Answer (score 9):

*Note: Being that this is the top google result for 'workbench how to duplicate a row' I feel inclined to provide an answer for that question. If a moderator feels this is inappropriate; feel free to help resolve the inappropriation.*

1. Select all columns (or your target columns) from a single table, without joins or anything else that restricts in-editor inserts.

   Eg: `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC`
2. right-click on the row you want to copy, <kbd>Copy Row</kbd>
3. Go to the bottom of the select results, <kbd>end</kbd>, there should be a line with all `null`'s
4. right-click on the null'ed row, <kbd>Paste Row</kbd>

   > Don't forget to nullify, or set to be the default, any columns you want to keep; like the primary index/id, or any unique constrained columns!
5. To insert your duplicated row use the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button on the lower right.

Workbench will open a dialog and show your the generated insert statements and offer to execute them for you. Permitting there are no errors you have just duplicated a row!

Run your select statement again to see your results.

Comment: for Mac OS X version 6.3.10, it's `Copy Rows (tabs separated)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is another way.  I would right-click on the table in MySQL Workbench, select "Send to SQL Editor" and "Select All Statement" as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. This functionality is also available in HeidiSQL, in the log window, after selecting the data tab to get a SELECT query, right click on the SELECT line in the log window and "Copy line to new query tab". Still, it would be nice to be able to do it in a kind of GROUP BY * except x query. It seems such a common thing to want to do.